# Laravel 5.2 : How to get the role of current user when using `Zizaco/entrust`?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2 and `Zizaco/entrust` 5.2,my question is:
How to get the role of current user when using `Zizaco/entrust`?

NameAndRole.php

```
namespace App\Services;

use App\User;
use App\Role;
use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

class NameAndRole
{
    public $username;
    public $role;

    public function __construct() {
        $user = \Auth::user();
        $this->username = $user->name;
        $this->role =$user->roles->first()->name;
    }
}
```

**Models:**

Role:https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust#role

```
<?php namespace App;

use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole;

class Role extends EntrustRole
{
}
```

User:https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust#user

```
<?php

use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;

class User extends Eloquent
{
    use EntrustUserTrait; // add this trait to your user model

    ...
}
```

**view:** sidebar.blade.php

```
@inject('details','App\Services\NameAndRole')
{{ $details->username }}
{{ $details->role }}
```

error:

```
ErrorException in NameAndRole.php line 20:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: D:\wnmp\www\laravel-entrust\resources\views\employer\partials\sidebar.blade.php) (View: D:\wnmp\www\laravel-entrust\resources\views\employer\partials\sidebar.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can access it like any other relationship in eloquent. So to access the roles of a user you can do:

```
$user->roles
```

This returns an eloquent collection as a `User` can have many `Role`s (i.e. it won't be just one), so if you're only expecting one role and you want the string value of it, you could do:

```
$user->roles->first()->name // or display_name
```

I guess you could cast it to an array using `toArray()` method, if you wanted to work with an array instead:

```
$user->roles->toArray()
```

**Edit**

You could check the user has a role before assigning it:

```
$this->role = $user->roles ? $user->roles->first()->name : 'No role';
```

Comment: The user has a role, right? If you get this type of error it's telling you that you're trying to access properties on something that doesn't exist. I assume here role or user doesn't exist. So you could try `dd($user->roles)` or `dd($user->roles->first()->name;)` before passing it to your view. See my answer edit also.

Comment: The result of `dd($user->roles->first()->name);` is:`Trying to get property of non-object`.Do I also need to define the relationship between user and roles in User.php  when I have used `Zizaco/entrust`?

Comment: Could you try everything in my last comment. (1) please confirm the user has a role. (2) try `dd($user->roles)` if it's empty you have no roles for that user. Regarding defining the relationship: it's in the `EntrustUserTrait` so no you shouldn't need to.

Answer (score 0):

To get the roles `id` field:

```
$user->roles->first()->id;
```

Comment: Can you improve your answer by explaining how your code resolves the problem?